# The underlying provider failed on Open in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, asp.net-web-api

I am using sql server 2014 to perform database operations, and it is working fine when I run from visual studio localhost. But when I put my web application on IIS on my system only, it is giving me error : The underlying provider failed on Open.

Both, application and database on single system. I googled it too, and I already followed this link, 
[Solution for "The underlying provider failed on Open" exception.](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/126919/Solution-for-The-underlying-provider-failed-on-Ope)[^]
But no luck.

What other changes I need to make to make it work. ?

Answer (score 0):

iis does not share local database first you grant permission to iis to use local DB

follow step

open visual studio command prompt and
type following command and enter. with command success database share with iis.

```
sqllocaldb share v11.0 IIS_DB
```

[image]

Comment: it says , the specified localdb instance is already shared with different shared name

Comment: I checked server roles in NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM in SQL security option, and its working